# Python, can't replace generator object

Tags: python, generator

I need to change replace a string's punctuation marks with space.
The problem is that I need to do it in one line.

for example: there's a string: `'H,+-=/e^@#%ll-!!..o'`

the result should be : `'H-----e----ll-----o'`

where `'-'` symbolizes `' '` (space)

when I do

```
replace((c for c in string.punctuation),' ')
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'generator' object to str implicitly
```

I tried to put it in a list, in a set even in a dict.
but this error keeps on coming back.

how can I surpass this?

Comment: Why do you have to do it in one line?

Answer (score 4):

`str.replace()` doesn't take a list or generator, it'd only take a string, and even then won't do what you want. The method replaces *one* whole sequence of characters with another, so even `x.replace(string.puntuation, '-')` would only replace whole occurrences of the `string.punctuation` string in `x` with one dash.

Use [`string.maketrans()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) instead:

```
import string

translationmap = string.maketrans(string.punctuation, '-' * len(string.punctuation))
x = x.translate(translationmap)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import string
>>> x = 'H,+-=/e^@#%ll-!!..o'
>>> import string
>>> translationmap = string.maketrans(string.punctuation, '-' * len(string.punctuation))
>>> x.translate(translationmap)
'H-----e----ll-----o'
```

`str.translate()` is hands-down the fastest method to map characters to other characters, or delete characters from a string.

On Python 3, `str.translate()` (or in Python 2, `unicode.translate()`) takes a mapping instead:

```
translationmap = {ord(c): '-' for c in string.punctuation}
x.translate(translationmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
import string
''.join(map(lambda x : '-' if x in string.punctuation else x,
       'H,+-=/e^@#%ll-!!..o'))
```

Comment: Rather than using `map` and a lambda, why not just a generator expression? `"".join(c if c not in string.punctuation else "-" for c in ugly_string)`

Comment: That's also a way to go. Anyway I think the most elegant method is to use translation maps as Martijn Pieters suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for this:

```
>>> from re import sub
>>> sub("\W", "-", "H,+-=/e^@#%ll-!!..o")
'H-----e----ll-----o'
>>>
```

[`\W`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) captures all non-word characters.

---

Note that the above code will keep underscores.  If you don't want them, replace `\W` with `[\W_]`.